# Calculate an indefinite-integral in function of a parameter

Tags: indefinite-integrals

The integral is this one:
$\int{dy\over (y^2+b^2)^{3/2}}$.
I know that the answer is $y\over b^2\sqrt{y^2+b^2}$ but I'd want to know how it's solve step by step.
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: If the parameter troubles you, get rid of it by the change of variable $z=by$.

Comment: what is your problem exactly? do you find the solutions given below hard to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y=b\tan(u)$ and $dy=b\sec^2(u)~du$.
$$\int \frac{b\sec^2(u)}{(b^2\tan^2(u)+b^2)^{3/2}}~du$$
$$=\int \frac{b\sec^2(u)}{(b^2(\tan^2(u)+1))^{3/2}}~du$$
$$=\int \frac{b\sec^2(u)}{b^3\sec^3(u)}~du$$
We thus obtain:
$$\frac{1}{b^2}\int \cos(u)~du$$
Solve this integral, and when substituting back from $y=b\tan(u)$, use the fact that $\sin(\arctan(x))\equiv \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$.

If done correctly, this should give the answer you've specified (plus the arbitrary constant of integration). Please let us know if you cannot get the answer from the above.

Answer (score 1):

Let us use the known integral

$$I_b:=\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y^2+b^2}}=\int\frac{dy}{b\sqrt{\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}+1}}=\text{arsinh}\frac yb+C_b$$

Then differentiating on $b$ under the integral,

$$I'_b=-\int\frac{b\,dy}{(y^2+b^2)^{3/2}}=-\frac y{b^2}\frac1{\sqrt{\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}+1}}+C'_b$$ and the claim follows.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int{dy\over (y^2+b^2)^{3/2}}$$ Let $$y=b \sinh(t)\implies dy=b\cosh(t)\,dt$$ This makes $$I=\frac{1}{b^2}\int\frac{dt}{\cosh^2(t)}=\frac{1}{b^2} \tanh (t)=\frac{1}{b^2} \frac{\sinh(t)}{\cosh (t)}=\frac{1}{b^2} \frac{\sinh(t)}{\sqrt{1+\sinh^2 (t)}}$$ Replace now $\sinh(t)$ by $\frac yb$ and simplify.